# Facebook Like button - only 1 line whhen no comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im using Facebook's like button plugin on my own website product pages, also using opengraph tags

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Everything seems to work fine, the problem is when people 'like' a product, the comment box shows up but if they leave it empty only single line is posted on their feed like:
Jon Doe has liked "title here".

But when they write that comment when they click Like or even post the the link manually all the image,text,description information is correctly displayed.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that’s the basic difference between a *like* and a *share*. Since Facebook has merged these to functionalities into one social plugin, it’s up to the user which action he takes.

The old [share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) has been deprecated, so not much use in implementing it now, because even if it’s still possible(?) it will stop working eventually.

If you want shares instead of likes, your one alternative IMHO is implementing the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) on your site, triggered by a click on a button of you own making.